# How to run Azure VM CustomScriptExtension as domain user? (part 1)

Tags: powershell, azure, windowsdomainaccount

What I have working is a Powershell script that takes a JSON file to create a new VM; the JSON file contains instructions for the VM to join a domain and run a custom script. Both things do happen, but the script runs as the user `workgroup\system` and therefore doesn't have access to a network drive.

- Does listing the extensions in this order *guarantee* that the script runs *after* the domain join is complete (or is it haphazard)?

Is there something I can do to ensure that the script does not run until the domain join is complete? How can I best detect (locally from the new VM) that the domain join is complete? How would you *delay* the running of the script until a better time (something like a once-off cron job)?

**Update:** Split question in two, other half is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36064904).

Also, *immense thanks* to [Dewi Jones](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6002663/dewi-jones) for more than an hour of interactive support. I'm indebted by being able to give only a single check mark in return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the domain and if the domain is equal to the one you are joining then continue.

```
$domain = gc env:UserDNSDomain

While ($domain -neq "FQDN")
{
Start-Sleep -seconds 2
}
```

Otherwise you can call a script using credentials as follows

```
$username = 'user'
$password = 'password'
$PSArgs = 'Script file name'
$securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $password -AsPlainText -Force
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential $username, $securePassword
Start-Process Powershell.exe -Credential $credential $PSArgs
```

Comment: This works beautifully (I think)! I added a delay and a time-out to the loop.

Comment: No Problem, Glad i could help, any issues feel free to let me know or DM me and ill see what i can do

Comment: "DM you" - I thought SE didn't allow for direct/private messages...?

Comment: Ah right, i'd have thought this site would have had that kind of feature, i'm fairly new to SE sorry

Comment: Sadly, this is one of the worse design decisions here.

Comment: Oh! Your domain-identifying solution breaks on Windows 7, though it works on Windows 10. Do you know what the minimum Powershell version is required?

Comment: it should be compatible on any version, just ran it into my test vm windows 7 pro 64bit and it worked okay for me

Comment: Sorry, had to remove the check mark -- I can't get the 2nd part to work. :-(

Comment: use localhost as the computername?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106591/discussion-between-dewi-jones-and-klaymendk).